# meteor build for android does not update client

Tags: android, meteor, client

Changing the client scripts on the server are not updating on the android app. The meteor server is set to run in the development mode. Browsers do update as always. The android
app with client side scripts embedded does not update ?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and tried changing the version number in the mobile-config.js file. but that triggered no refresh.

`App.info({
    "id": "your.app.id",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "your app name"
});`

so i [installed adb](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378?disableinsets=on&utm_expid=66866090-49.VYy4WCNHSyuP6EmjnM93MQ.2)

after installing adb you can do

`adb uninstall your_app_id
meteor run android-device`

and its refreshing again. Adb uninstalls the app on your device.

i also created an alias because i need it often.

`alias mrad="adb uninstall your_app_id && meteor run android-device"`

i think its important for running that command, that you define the id in the file mobile-config.js in the root folder of the meteor project like stated above.

Answer (score 0):

meteor says "Every time the mobile app client notices a new version"....
So changing the code is not enough, the 'version' must be changed for an update to happen.

Comment: How do I change the version?